# Menu on button click

Tags: android, android-menu

I created a menu for my activity with 3 item with

```
 showAsAction="never"
```

so in the right corner of the toolbar I have the menu button and when I click on it the menu appear in the right corner of the screen.

But if I press the menu button on the smartphone, the same menu appear in the bottom left corner.

How can I always open the top menu?

Comment: Consider whether it's worth violating user expectations - if they have a hardware menu button, it will open the menu from the bottom in all apps with menus, not just yours.

Answer (score 0):

> it depends on android version,so for always top.you will have to create your own custom dial

Comment: In which way can I create my custom dial?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void showStatusPopup(final Activity context, Point p) 
{
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pop_up, null);
ListView l = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list);
String s[] = null;

final UserBean user = Utill.getUserPreferance(mContext);
if (user.isUserLogin()) {
    s = loginMenuOptions;
} 
else {
    s = unknownUserOptions;
}


ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.simpletextview, R.id.tvName, s);
l.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
// Creating the PopupWindow
final PopupWindow changeStatusPopUp = new PopupWindow(context);
changeStatusPopUp.setContentView(layout);
changeStatusPopUp.setWidth(330);
//changeStatusPopUp.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
changeStatusPopUp.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
changeStatusPopUp.setFocusable(true);

// Some offset to align the popup a bit to the left, and a bit down,
// relative to button's position.
int OFFSET_X = VIEW_POART_WIDTH - 290;
int OFFSET_Y = 0;

// Clear the default translucent background
changeStatusPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

// Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
changeStatusPopUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) { 
            changeStatusPopUp.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
}
```